# Use grep and cut inside a bash function

Tags: bash, function, curl, grep, cut

i have the following bash code:

```
function () {
   curl="$(curl -s "$2" >> "$1")"
   version="$(grep '$3' $1 | $4 )"
   echo $version
}

function "test" "https://google.com" "String" "cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d'<' -f1"
```

Basically the function downloads the page and then uses grep to look for a specific string. After that "cut", cuts down the results further. But ... unfortenatly the cut inside the function doesn't work. I only get the following output:

```
"usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]"
```

Maybe i overlooked something ... or maybe you have a better idea :-)

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: `function` is a bash builtin command/keyword. See: `help`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `curl="$(curl ...)"`, as you don't ever use the `curl` variable after that.

Comment: yeah, there won't be anything in it anyway. stdout is redirected, and stderr won't be collected into the var.

Comment: A yes the curl variable was nonse and the function isn't titled function of course. It was just for the posting here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$4` contains shell metacharacters that aren't processed when expanding variables, you need to use `eval` to execute it.

Also, you need to put `$3` in double quotes, not single quotes, otherwise the variable won't be expanded.

```
   version="$(grep "$3" "$1" | eval "$4" )"
```